# How to use ngcordova facebook and push notification plugins in single ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

when i am using ngCordova facebook and pushNotification plugins in same app and build the app then find the following error.

========================================================================
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  >   /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/anurag/my-works/fbPush/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/anurag/my-works/fbPush/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  >   Error Code:
  >   2
  >   Output:

  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 38.579 secs

/home/anurag/my-works/fbPush/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/anurag/my-works/fbPush/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/anurag/my-works/fbPush/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my app and i solved it by removing my cordova facebook plugin and adding this one : https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

My push notification plugin is : phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: i solved the problem committing a line in project.properties #cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:+ but when i using ng-cordova google analytics then facing same problem.

Comment: @Romain Matineau did you manage to get cordova-plugin-facebook4 working by switching to the native Facebook app in iOS? (for me that plugin opens Facebook in Safari, even after following Facebook's "preparing for iOS 9" instructions)

Comment: @John i'm actually working in **Android**, but but in my case the plugin open correctly the native app. I ll try on IOs asap.

Comment: @RomainMartineau Thanks for the reply! The consensus based on the FAQs in Facebook's [preparing for iOS 9 page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) seems to be that this is by design, as using a SafariViewController does not trigger iOS 9's "this app wants to open another app" prompt and so requires less taps to complete the authentication. That said, please do let us know if you find any other info on this.