# What is the best solution for facebook login in cordova / web / hybrid apps?

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I would like to have a facebook authorization and facebook shares in my cordova app. So I need a plugin / solution for this case.

I found **[cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4)** but it didn't have updates for a long time and doesn't work properly with last Cordova/Facebook SDK.

I also have tried to use **[OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB)** but it has two main problems: it also has some troubles and works via JS SDK which mean my app asks a user for a password while login even if there is a facebook app on the smartphone.

I use poor JS and Jquery (not ionic, not Angular, etc).
I want to use it for Android and iOS both.
I want to have a native login window (not the web based).

Could you recommend something for me and community?

Comment: The cordova-plugin-facebook4 repository you linked to was updated 2 days ago?  It's the version I personally use for facebook integration in Cordova.

Comment: @JordanBurnett what version of cordova do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one? Looks like the best:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Also for sharing, I use this, and works like a charm:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: I have Cordova 5.4.1 and it has problems with duplicating "android support v4" (Landroid/support/v4). I spent almost half a day to fix it, still didn't fix and it stealed almost all my energy – can't anymore.

Comment: @ Kir Mazur , view this  [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727318/cordova-multiple-dex-files-define-annotation/33777507#33777507) and also view this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361338/how-to-use-ngcordova-facebook-and-push-notification-plugins-in-single-ionic-app)

Comment: @AnuragPandey it didn't work for me but I have already don this another way. Thanks!

Comment: add this to project.properties to resolve the V4 error stuff. cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0